Spring Boot: How spring boot handle if we use both @Component and @Bean annotation for same class
In my spring boot application. I created a class name Book and annotated that class with @Component annotation. Then I created a AppConfig class with @Configration annotation and in that class created a method name getBook() annotated with @Bean annotation which returns Book object.
So I was accepting a error as : required a single bean, but 2 were found when I will use @Autowird annotation to inject it but it not gave me any error and created two beans. So I observed that if I use the below code to inject it:
@Autowired
Book book;

It not gives me any error as here instance name is book.
But if I inject it as:
@Autowired
Book obj;

It gives me error as : required a single bean, but 2 were found
Can anyone tell me why it is like that.

Book class code:

@Component
public class Book {

    void readBook() {
        System.out.println("reading book");
    }

}


AppConfig class code:

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    Book getBook() {
        return new Book();
    }
}


Main class code where I inject it and gets 2 bean found error:

@SpringBootApplication
public class IntroductionToSpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Book obj;




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(IntroductionToSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      
    }
}


Main class code where I inject it and gets no error:

@SpringBootApplication
public class IntroductionToSpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Book book;




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(IntroductionToSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      
    }
}


Try changing @Autowired Book obj; to @Autowired Book getBook; and see if you get an error. Also, what version of spring are you using?

Spring boot version : 3.3.1 and java version 22

If I use @Autowired Book getBook; it not gives any error. Why it so when the instance name contains book it not gives error but when I use some random name it gives error.

Autowiring by name.

@Yousaf that is wrong, autowiring by name still happens. However there has been a change in name resolution, it now only works if you compile with -parameters enabled. If you don't the parameter names will not be retained in the class file.

@M.Deinum got it, thanks for the correction.

You will endup with 2 instances of Book, one named book (due to the @Component) and one named getBook due to the method-name of the @Bean method.
When there are multiple instances of a bean found Spring will try to find a bean named after the field. In your initial case it would thus inject the one named book created by the @Component.
When changing it to obj there is no name to match and thus it will fail to inject and you will get the error as mentioned.
You could also add an @Primary to the getBook method (or the component) and then that instance would be used if multiple instances would be found.
All of this is also explained in the, imho excellent, Spring Framework Reference Guide.

One of the main purposes of spring is inversion of control or dependency injection. In very simple terms, you do not have to create instance of the object manually but spring will provide you an implementation for you. With modern spring it can happen with Annotations. When you annotate a class with code scanning annotations like @Service or @Component or @Configuration or any other composite annotation which triggers code scanning, Spring will try to create instance of the object at run time. Now, sometimes we do not (or can not in case of third party code) add these annotations to the class. In that case you can provide @Bean annotation with implementation on how to construct the object. And when you @Autowired a class, any of these mechanisms will try to create the instance of the class to inject.
So long story short, there are multiple ways in triggering the class instance creation for spring and above are just two simple ways I mentioned. Depending on your use case (and it looks like you have control over the code, so if you do not need to do anything special to the book instance), then I would suggest to get rid of the @Bean for getBook and clean up the code. Now, spring will find only one way of creating the instance and you will not get the error anymore.
Again, this is barely scratching the surface with Spring's core tenent but should allow you to walk towards one direction. Good luck!
